# Save Result of Shell Script SQLite Select Statement to Variable

Tags: linux, sqlite, shell

I'm pretty new to shell scripts and am only doing them because its about time I learnt and I need to for work.

I have been looking around and have tried multiple methods to get this working but can't seem to figure it out.

I have a script in which I want to access an SQLite database and store the result of a select statement in a variable.

**What I've Tried So Far**

This one just echoes whats inside the apostrophe. If I remove the dollar sign before the apostrophe I get the same outcome.

```
track_name=$'sqlite3 "$database_name" << EOF
select name from track where id = "$required_track";
exit;
EOF'
```

Here I get a syntax error near "track_name"

```
sqlite3 "$database_name" << EOF
track_name='select name from track where id = "$required_track";'
exit;
EOF
```

I have successfully executed the select statement without trying to store it in a variable but its not much use to me without being able to store it...

**Any help would be much appreciated**

Answer (score 2):

To store the output of a command into a BASH variable you should use:

```
VAR_NAME=$(command);
```

For example, if you want to store your system current time into a variable or 
the results of a list directory command ejecution:

```
DATE_EXAMPLE_VAR=$(date); #Stores 'date' command output into DATE_EXAMPLE_VAR
echo $DATE_EXAMPLE_VAR; #Shows DATE_EXAMPLE_VAR contents

DIRCONTENTS=$(ls); #Stores a list of your current directory contents.
```

Similarly, this should work for `sqlite3`:

```
track_name=$(sqlite3 "$database_name" "select name from track where id = $required_track")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. All its doing is echoing the statement. What is the end portion for `| sqlite3`